# installing rosserial_Arduino error

Tags: ros, rosseral-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

when i run :

```
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial
```

i get the next error:

```
abort: error: _ssl.c:504:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
verify failed
```

I was searching some solution but i dont find anything . any help?
thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52949/installing-rosserial_arduino-error/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The certificate is not correct (expired). You can add the option --insecure to your command to disable certificate validation.

hg clone --insecure  https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1